# Appropriate Table Schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a system which checks if the customer has brought the needed documents. In the system, the admin should check the checkboxes of each documents.

What would be the appropriate table for this? Do I need to make a tblDocuments to lists all the documents and tblUserDocuments to lists all the documents brought by the user and compare the 2 tables?

Answer (score -1):

This may be help you:

```
create table c_record (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    mobile_number int,
    email_id varchar(50),
    gov_documnet_name varchar(50) not null,
    doc_id text not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```